# Dark font for R in notepad++

Tags: windows-7, notepad++, colors, r, color-theme

When I go into the style configurator in Notepad++ and change the theme to something darker, like obsidian or monokai, all of my R files are monochromatic. In the default white theme this is not the case. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Style Configurator, check to see that Language is Global Style, Style is Global override, and everything is unchecked. That should make it work, then go from there. (Tested on a fresh Notepad++ with Obsidian and Haskell.)

***Edit:*** Turns out R is not in by default, so [this](http://blog.tersmitten.nl/editing-and-running-r-scripts-with-notepad.html) adds in syntax highlighting and more.

Comment: I did that, but there still is no style for R.

Comment: Try downloading the zip or 7z file, extract it, and run it from there. Also, am I correct to presume R normally has syntax highlighting?

Comment: yeah it normally does

Comment: Still does not work when I run the zip version

Comment: Can you try it with something other than R? For example, some Haskell that worked for me was `potatoizer x = x ++ " is a potato!"` as `potatoizer.hs`. That will get it narrowed down to Notepad++ or R.

Comment: the haskell is colored, the problem is definitely with R

Comment: Are you saving the R file first with the right extension?

Comment: yep, as a .r extension

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6770/discussion-between-bb010g-and-user1876508)